# Skew coordinate systems do not allow separation of variables - proof?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, harmonic-functions, laplacian

In their [Field Theory Handbook](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-83243-7_1), while discussing eleven coordinate systems in which Helmholtz equation is separable, Moon and Spencer state that: "Skew coordinate systems do not allow separation of variables and will not be considered."

Since they do not provide any proof of this statement, I presume that this should be self-evident. However, I am unable to see why this must be true and would appreciate any clarification or, better yet, a rigorous proof.

My question: why don't skew coordinate systems allow separation of variables?

Comment: I think this is far from trivial. See for example the last section in this paper by Benenti (which is about Hamilton–Jacobi and geodesics, but Laplace and Helmholtz and all that is related): http://dx.doi.org/10.3842/SIGMA.2016.013

Comment: Thank you for a nice reference. As far as I can tell, it is, indeed, highly nontrivial.

Comment: If you expand your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: OK, I've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a nontrivial theorem.

For a similar statement in a related but slightly different setting, see Section 12 in the paper [Separability in Riemannian Manifolds](http://dx.doi.org/10.3842/SIGMA.2016.013) by Sergio Benenti (2016).

Comment: I have a related question. The standard eleven coordinate systems in which the Helmholtz equation (HE) is separable are based on second-order surfaces. I take this to mean that the HE is possibly separable in other, more complicated, coordinate systems (third-order, forth-order...) Are there any general results in this direction? E.g. can a complete classification of all possible coordinate systems in which HE is separable be made?

Comment: I think those standard coordinate system *are* the result of a classification, i.e., there are no others. A least for Hamilton–Jacobi, which I'm more familiar with, that's the case. Except if you allow more exotic transformations where you mix positions and momenta, but that's a different game. However, it's a rather long and complicated story, and I don't know all the details (far from it, in fact). Look for papers by Benenti and by Kalnins & Miller, and follow the references from there.